# Adding multiples of an item to a form, without javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

**Thanks everybody.** (For some reason I couldn't up vote answers, so everyone wins today :] thanks again!)

---

Complete php and javascript novice here, apologize up front for anything half-witted.

I have a portion of a user's profile in which I'd like the user to be able to add additional items of the same thing, with slightly different conditions.

For example, let's say it's favorite books. A fieldset contains some checkboxes for genre and an input text box for the title of a book. After the user checks a genre and fills in a title, they can add the book to their set of favorite books and then have the option to add another. When done adding books, they move on to the next fieldset, complete the form and submit.

How is this done? And more-importantly, is it possible without javascript?

Without JS, I understand this probably entails a lot of reloading of the page to add the items, regardless I'm more confused about how the $_POST data is handled, both before and after the submit.

Sorry for such an open ended question, really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, as searching for this topic proved to be a bit difficult.

Thanks.

**Some Clarification**
I'm trying to develop an application that is as independent of javascript as possible. In that sense, I don't know if it's possible to add the new items with PHP alone. My sense is the fieldset in question could have it's own submit button, the action of which POSTS to the page itself (no DB interaction, etc), and variables like $book_genre1, $book_title1 are populated in the page. Then, the "official" submit is sent later, which actually adds the POST data, which contains the books array, to the DB. But I don't know if that is a safe procedure or good logic to begin with.

Comment: If you want to do it without Javascript, then why is this question tagged "javascript"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to the above answer, if that is exactly what you need since I seem to have a different idea.

You simply store each addition in an array stored inside a session variable, and in each page load, parse the data into readable html.

```
$_SESSION['form'][] = serialized_form_data;
```

On each load,

```
foreach ($_SESSION['form'] as $form) {
    unserialize_data_and_create_html(); 
}

add_new_form_element();
```

I'm assuming you want to show the user already filled forms so he can deal with them as he wishes.

This is a better implementation than what I thought of earlier. I wanted to implement a db version.

Sorry for the delay. I can't comment since I'm mobile (js issues) so I decided to edit instead.

You can simply use the `$_SESSION['form']` for your inserts.

A simple `foreach` will work as well. However, remember to sanitize each value properly before inserting it. That's the key.

If you use prepared statements with binding, you have the advantage of clean input as well as better database performance.

Comment: Thanks Frosty. I'm new to SESSION, but this seems like a smart use.For the final sumbit, would I simply use $_SESSION['form'] in my SQL INSERT statements as well? Or would it make more sense to set the parsed data as new variables, and use those instead?

Answer (score 0):

What you're really asking is how to persist information between POSTs of the same form. The most common and effective way of doing so is to just use the inputs on the form. If you have information that shouldn't be displayed then use hidden input elements for them.

Note that storing information in the form like this is not considered secure since it can be manipulated and/or forged, so the next option is to store it in the session; since it is server-side only the cookie/session ID needs to be protected. The values can then be retrieved from the session in PHP after the POST has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit a form...there is no data to handle. Once a form is submitted data then is sent to the server in the form of an array.

(From php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

> $_POST = "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method."

So a user submits some data to the server. Now that data is available to your scripts for use: Populate a database, validate the values before doing "x", write HTML to the client, etc.

I like where @frosty is going with his approach. It does potentially send multiple requests to the server, but it's also a very straight forward approach. A completely server-side solution.

JavaScript or the jQuery Library would allow you to accomplish a similar result, and post to the server just once - by simply hiding/showing populated fields, writing additional fields to the form dynamically (eg: After completing "book #1" the user can click "Add another" and JS writes an identical set of form fields all referencing book #2). Obviously, this approach will get more involved than a straight PHP approach. And you'll need a backup plan if you want to allow users with JS disabled to participate.

Comment: Example of JS and PHP building a form together http://mitmmarketing.com/employment/project-manager

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to develop an application that is as independent of javascript as possible. In that sense, I don't know if it's possible to dynamically add new items with PHP alone. My sense is the segment of the profile in question gets it's own submit, the action of which is the page itself (no DB interaction, etc).

Comment: My mention of JS was only to allow you to potentially build a very large form client-side, but keep the UI very compact, and potentially send ONE "finished" post to the server after the user had completed all additions/edits. I only like JS here for its ability to keep the UI trim...not as a stand alone solution.

Comment: Just saw your edit above. No - there is no way for PHP to build the "official" post without sending chunks of data to the server. Using the $_SESSION approach would allow you to build a "preliminary" data set, to be used as the "official" (which is why I liked it). Only touches the DB upon "official" post.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use javascript to handle the user adding multiple items. Check out jQuery (http://www.jquery.com) which is a fantastic javascript library that will help you do lots of great dynamic things.

Then once you have all of the information from the user, just once it all at once to your php and save it. For information about to access and use $_POST or $_REQUEST, you'll need to check out some PHP tutorials or pick up a book. That's fairly basic PHP stuff and too large a topic for this thread.

Comment: -1 I'd recommend this too, but it doesn't answer the question. Perhaps you meant to make it a comment.

Comment: Tomalak, the poster asked "Sorry for such an open ended question, really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, as searching for this topic proved to be a bit difficult." He's not asking a specific question with a specific answer, he's looking for a good direction to help solve his problem. jQuery is a great resource to handle the complex stuff he's trying to do. I think my response is legit and helpful.

Comment: The question asks "is this possible without Javascript?" and the title has in it the text "without javascript". I have no idea why you answered with a Javascript solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, his clarification explaining that he wants to do it independently from javascript was added after my answer. Yes, he asked if it was possible to do without javascript and Dawson had already given him an answer about multiple form posts. Since it was an open ended question and he was asking if it was _possible_ w/o Javascript I decided to offer him a jQuery suggestion. Many people avoid JS because it is painful at times, jQuery makes it less painful so I thought it would be helpful.

Comment: There are lots of things that would be helpful! But unless they answer the question, they should be comments...